# How to perform atomic operations on Linux that work on x86, arm, GCC and icc?

Tags: c++, c, linux, atomic

Every Modern OS provides today some atomic operations:

- Windows has `Interlocked*` API
- FreeBSD has `<machine/atomic.h>`
- Solaris has `<atomic.h>`
- Mac OS X has `<libkern/OSAtomic.h>`

Anything like that for Linux?

- I need it to work on most Linux supported platforms including: x86, x86_64 and  **arm**.
- I need it to work on at least GCC and Intel Compiler.
- I need not to use 3rd par library like glib or qt.
- I need it to work in C++ (C not required)

Issues:

- GCC atomic builtins `__sync_*` are not supported on all platforms (ARM) and are not supported by the Intel compiler.
- AFAIK `<asm/atomic.h>` should not be used in user space and I haven't successfully used it at all. Also, I'm not sure if it would work with Intel compiler.

**Any suggestions?**

I know that there are many related questions but some of them point to `__sync*` which is not feasible for me (ARM) and some point to `asm/atomic.h`.

Maybe there is an inline assembly library that does this for GCC (ICC supports gcc assembly)?

**Edit:**

There is a very partial solution for add operations only (allows implementing atomic counter but not lock free-structures that require CAS):

If you use `libstc++` (Intel Compiler uses `libstdc++`) then you can use `__gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add` that defined in `<ext/atomicity.h>` or `<bits/atomicity.h>`. Depends on compiler version.

However I'd still like to see something that supports CAS.

Comment: @KennyTM Good questions. AFAIK ll/sc are only available on arm6 and above? So it probably would be relevant only for arm6 and above

Comment: So let's clarify that - are GCC intrinsics not supported on ARM because of GCC toolchain shortcomings or because of the ARM shortcomings? Can you confirm that you can't use them with GCC for ARM which does support those atomic ops?

Comment: ARM shortcomings. Some related support instructions:
ARM v5: SWP(atomic swap word size and byte size)

ARM v6: LDREX/STREX(32 bit chained possibly atomic load/store)+SWP

ARM v7: LDREX/STREX(same as v6, but with size options for 8/16bits)

V5 can't do an atomic increment without disabling interrupts, userspace doesn't get to do. However, what it can do is call up to the operating system with say, a software interrupt, and have the OS handle it instead.

Comment: Similar for C but not requiring so much portability: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353371/atomic-increment-fetch

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Projects are using this:

http://packages.debian.org/source/sid/libatomic-ops

If you want simple operations such as CAS, can't you just just use the arch-specific implementations out of the kernel, and do arch checks in user-space with autotools/cmake? As far as licensing goes, although the kernel is GPL, I think it's arguable that the inline assembly for these operations is provided by Intel/AMD, not that the kernel has a license on them. They just happen to be in an easily accessible form in the kernel source.

Answer (score 15):

Recent standards (from 2011) of C & C++ now specify atomic operations:

- C11: [`stdatomic.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29#Changes_from_C99)
- C++11: [`std::atomic`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Threading_facilities)

Regardless, your platform or compiler may not support these newer headers & features.

Comment: IIRC, for GCC, this might require use of libatomic.

Comment: @Hasturkun: Which version of GCC? Is that still the case for the recent GCC releases?

Comment: @Isaac: According to the [GCC Wiki on the C++11 memory model](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM), as of GCC 4.7 libatomic may be required when lock-free instructions aren't available. GCC 4.8 includes libatomic in its source tree.

Answer (score 3):

Darn.  I was going to suggest the GCC primitives, then you said they were off limits.  :-)

In that case, I would do an `#ifdef` for each architecture/compiler combination you care about and code up the inline asm.  And maybe check for `__GNUC__` or some similar macro and use the GCC primitives if they are available, because it feels so much more right to use those.  :-)

You are going to have a lot of duplication and it might be difficult to verify correctness, but this seems to be the way a lot of projects do this, and I've had good results with it.

Some gotchas that have bit me in the past: when using GCC, don't forget "`asm volatile`" and clobbers for `"memory"` and `"cc"`, etc.

Comment: I've ended up with `asm volatile` not being volatile, though I suspect that phenomenon is not limited just to inline assembly.

Comment: the problem with the gcc primitives, is that in some versions they are in fact available, but there is no feature test macro to test for them.

Answer (score 1):

Boost, which has a non intrusive license, and other frameworks already offer portable atomic counters -- as long as they are supported on the target platform.

Third party libraries are good for us. And if for strange reasons your company forbid you from using them, you can still have a look at how they proceed (as long as the licence permit it for your use) to implement what your are looking for.

Comment: Which Boost library includes these?

Comment: It's part of the common details: http://boost.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/boost/boost/boost/detail/atomic_count.hpp?revision=1.13&view=markup

Comment: (a) Boost falls back to pthreads frequently, in fact for ARM it would use pthreads. (b) `atomic_counters` provide only inc/dec operations that are fine for reference counting but they are too weak. If you need something like atomic linked list where you need operations like CAS.

Comment: "And if for strange reasons your company forbid you from using them" I do not forbid I just prefer not to use 3rd part libraries to reduce an about of dependencies to build certain project.

Answer (score 1):

I recently did an implementation of such a thing and I was confronted to the same difficulties as you are. My solution was basically the following:

- try to detect the gcc builtins with
  the feature macro
- if not available just implement
  something like `cmpxch` with `__asm__` for the other architectures (ARM is a bit more complicated than that). Just do that for one possible size, e.g `sizeof(int)`.
- implement all other functionality on
  top of that one or two primitives
  with `inline` functions

Answer (score 1):

There is a patch for GCC here to support ARM atomic operations. WIll not help you on Intel, but you could examine the code - there is recent kernel support for older ARM architectures, and newer ones have the instructions built in, so you should be able to build something that works.

http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2011-07/msg00050.html

Answer (score 1):

`__sync*` certainly is (and has been) supported by the Intel compiler, because GCC adopted these build-ins from there. Read the first paragraph [on this page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html). Also see "[Intel® C++ Compiler for Linux* Intrinsics Reference](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/courses/HPC-adv/intref_cls.pdf)", page 198. It's from **2006** and describes exactly those built-ins.

Regarding ARM support, for older ARM CPUs: it cannot be done entirely in userspace, but it can be done in kernelspace (by disabling interrupts during the operation), and I think I read somewhere that it is supported for quite a while now.

According to [this PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55874), dated 2011-10-08, `__sync_*` will only fail on

- PA-RISC with anything other than Linux
- SPARCv7 and lower
- ARM with GCC < 4.3
- ARMv5 and lower with anything other than Linux
- MIPS1

So with GCC > 4.3 (and 4.7 is the current one), you shouldn't have a problem with ARMv6 and newer. You shouldn't have no problem with ARMv5 either as long as compiling for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian/Ubuntu recommend...

sudo apt-get install libatomic-ops-dev

examples: http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/atomic_ops/example.php4

GCC & ICC compatible.

compared to Intel Thread Building Blocks (TBB), using atomic< T >, libatomic-ops-dev is over twice as fast! (Intel compiler)

Testing on Ubuntu i7 producer-consumer threads piping 10 million ints down a ring buffer connection in 0.5secs as opposed to 1.2secs for TBB

And easy to use e.g.

volatile AO_t head;

AO_fetch_and_add1(&head);

Answer (score 0):

See: [kernel_user_helpers.txt](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/arm/kernel_user_helpers.txt) or [entry-arm.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S) and look for `__kuser_cmpxchg`.  As seen in comments of other ARM Linux versions,

### kuser_cmpxchg

```
Location:       0xffff0fc0

Reference prototype:

  int __kuser_cmpxchg(int32_t oldval, int32_t newval, volatile int32_t *ptr);

Input:

  r0 = oldval
  r1 = newval
  r2 = ptr
  lr = return address

Output:

  r0 = success code (zero or non-zero)
  C flag = set if r0 == 0, clear if r0 != 0

Clobbered registers:

  r3, ip, flags

Definition:

  Atomically store newval in *ptr only if *ptr is equal to oldval.
  Return zero if *ptr was changed or non-zero if no exchange happened.
  The C flag is also set if *ptr was changed to allow for assembly
  optimization in the calling code.

Usage example:
```

```
 typedef int (__kuser_cmpxchg_t)(int oldval, int newval, volatile int *ptr);
 #define __kuser_cmpxchg (*(__kuser_cmpxchg_t *)0xffff0fc0)

 int atomic_add(volatile int *ptr, int val)
 {
        int old, new;

        do {
                old = *ptr;
                new = old + val;
        } while(__kuser_cmpxchg(old, new, ptr));

        return new;
}
```

**Notes:**

- This routine already includes memory barriers as needed.
- Valid only if __kuser_helper_version >= 2 (from kernel version 2.6.12).

This is for use with Linux with ARMv3 using the `swp` primitive.  You must have a very ancient ARM not to support this.  Only a *data abort* or *interrupt* can cause the spinning to fail, so the kernel monitors for this address *~0xffff0fc0* and performs a *user space* `PC` fix-up when either a *data abort* or an *interrupt* occurs.  All user-space libraries that support ARMv5 and lower will use this facility.

For instance, *QtConcurrent* uses this.