# atomic operations in Solaris studio on linux

Tags: linux, gcc, solaris, atomic

I could not find `<atomic.h>`, I guess this is only found on Solaris but not on Linux.
I know that gcc has __sync intrinsics which I can use but,
How can I get atomic operations to work with Solaris Studio C/C++ compiler?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287451/how-to-perform-atomic-operations-on-linux -> Atomic operations in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

There is no special support for atomics on Linux in Sun Studio. You could try including `<asm-generic/atomic.h>` or `<asm/atomic.h>` and see how they work. Later compilers have added additional support for gcc extensions and linux assembler syntax.

Taken from: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=8451594