# Equivalent of InterlockedExchangeAdd for Linux using Delphi 10.2)

Tags: linux, delphi, atomic

Delphi 10.2 (having support for Linux) has a cross Platform function AtomicExchange which is equivalent to Windows InterlocekdEchange. So far so good...

I have to port Win32 code making use of InterlockedExchangeAdd which has no AtomicExchangeAdd equivalent.

My question is: what can I use to replace InterlockedExchangeAdd when compiling for Linux ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2287451/505088

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`InterlockedExchangeAdd()` "performs an atomic addition of *Value* to the value pointed to by *Addend*. The result is stored in the address specified by *Addend*."

The `System.SyncObjs` unit has a [`TInterlocked`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.TInterlocked) class, which has overloaded [`Add()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.TInterlocked.Add) methods to do the same thing:

> Increments an integer value with another.
>
> There are two overloaded `Add` methods. Both `Add` methods increment a `Target` by `Increment`.

```
class function Add(var Target: Integer; Increment: Integer): Integer; overload; static; inline;

class function Add(var Target: Int64; Increment: Int64): Int64; overload; static; inline;
```

The difference is that `InterlockedExchangeAdd()` "returns the **initial value** of the variable pointed to by *Addend*", whereas `TInterlocked.Add()` "returns the value of the **incremented parameter**" instead.  So, if you use the return value, you will have to account for that difference, eg:

```
function InterlockedExchangeAdd(var Addend: Integer; Value: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := TInterlocked.Add(Addend, Value) - Value;
end;
```

Comment: Is this really interlocked (atomic) ? By the way, TInterlocked is just a wrapper around AtomicXYZ function.

Comment: @fpiette yes, it ks a wrapper, but it is also a public cross-platform interface for atomic operations.

Comment: `AtomicIncrement` etc. are also public cross-platform. You can pick either.

Answer (score 11):

There is a hidden implementation of this function in *System.SysUtils.pas*:

```
function AtomicExchangeAdd(var Addend: Integer; Value: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := AtomicIncrement(Addend, Value) - Value;
end;
```

It makes use of the fact that *AtomicIncrement* returns the new value of *Addend*, while *InterlockedExchangeAdd* returns the old value. Subtracting *Value* gives the expected result and obviously is thread-safe.